# How to web scrape data using Python from an html table and store it in a csv file. I am able to extract some parts but not the others

Tags: python, html, csv, asp-classic, web-scraping

I am beginner in Web scraping and I have become very much interested in the process. I set for myself a Project that can keep me motivated till I completed the project.

**My Project**

My Aim is to write a Python Program that goes to my university results page and scrape all the results of a range of students and store each of their marks in each subject in a .csv file or , delimited text file. I have gotten the code working to submit the post request to the .asp page. I would appreciate it if you could guide me on how to store the subject wise details in separate columns like:

**Desired Output:**

Sl.no,Name,Subject1,Subject2,Subject3,Subject4,Subject5,Subject6,..etc

1,Jason,8,9,8,8,8,9..etc

2,Peter,6,8,9,8,7,7..etc

.

.

.

for a series of exam numbers.

**Some Sample Data to try it out**

**The Results Website**: http://result.pondiuni.edu.in/candidate.asp

**Register Number**: 15te1218

**Degree**: BTHEE

**Exam**: Second

Could anyone give me directions on how I am to accomplish the task?
 Please correct me and would be awesome if you could guide me to solve the problem.

Can this be done in a much more simple way ?

In the code below you can see that I have tried to print out the name of the student but it returns an empty set(doesn't work). and i don't want it to return the data as a set because there is only one occurrence of that detail.

I do not know how to extract the Subject Names and the corresponding mark of that student from the html table in the results page. Some help with this is needed.

**Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import re
import csv

for x in xrange(44,47):

    EXAMNO ='15te12'+str(x)
    print EXAMNO

    data = {"txtregno": EXAMNO,
        "cmbdegree": r"BTHEE~\BTHEE\result.mdb", # use raw strings
        "cmbexamno": "B",
        "dpath": r"\BTHEE\result.mdb",
        "dname": "BTHEE",
        "txtexamno": "B"}

results_page = requests.post("http://result.pondiuni.edu.in/ResultDisp.asp", data=data).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(results_page, 'html.parser').prettify()
regpa= "<!--Percentage / S.G.P.A : <b>(.+?) </b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; -->"
patterngpa =re.compile(regpa)
gpa=re.findall(patterngpa,soup)
print gpa
rename="<font size=3 color=black>(.+?)</font>"
patternname=re.compile(rename)
name=re.findall(patternname,soup)
    print (name)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
15te1244
[u'8.67']
15te1245
[u'8.8']
[]
15te1246
[u'7.8']
[]
```

Would be helpful if you could show me how to print it in the desired output format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a lot of time to find a brute force solution.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import re
import csv
for x in xrange(44,47):
    EXAMNO ='15te12'+str(x)
    data = {"txtregno": EXAMNO,
    "cmbdegree": r"BTHEE~\BTHEE\result.mdb", # use raw strings
    "cmbexamno": "B",
    "dpath": r"\BTHEE\result.mdb",
    "dname": "BTHEE",
    "txtexamno": "B"}
    results_page = requests.post("http://result.pondiuni.edu.in/ResultDisp.asp", data=data).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(results_page, 'html.parser').prettify()
    string=str(BeautifulSoup(results_page, 'html.parser'))
    regpa= "<!--Percentage / S.G.P.A : <b>(.+?) </b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; -->"
    print (re.search(regpa,string,re.M|re.I )).group(1) 
    regname="<b>Name of the student : <b><font color=\"black\" size=\"3\">(.*)</font></b></b>"
    print (re.search(regname,string,re.M|re.I )).group(1)
    regsub="66%\"><font color=\"black\" face=\"arial\" size=\"2\">(.*)</font></td>"
    matches=(re.findall(regsub,string,re.M|re.I ))

    for i in xrange(len(matches)):
        regsubm=">"+matches[i]+"</font></td>\n<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"white\" width=\"2%\"><font color=\"black\" face=\"arial\" size=\"2\">..</font></td>\n<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"white\" width=\"7%\"><font color=\"black\" face=\"arial\" size=\"2\">[\xc2]?[\xa0]?[\xc2]?[\xa0]?-</font></td>\n<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"white\" width=\"1%\"><font color=\"black\" face=\"arial\" size=\"2\">-</font></td>\n<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"white\" width=\"5%\"><font color=\"black\" face=\"arial\" size=\"2\">-</font></td>\n<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"white\" width=\"5%\"><font color=\"black\" face=\"arial\" size=\"2\">(.*)</font>"
        matchesm=re.findall(regsubm,string,re.M)
        print matches[i],'--->',matchesm[0]
```

Comment: Works perfectly !! I greatly appreciate you for taking the time to help me out man !! Thanks.. Could you explain a bit on how the name extraction part works ? and I;d like to know what re.M|re.I is in    " print (re.search(regpa,string,re.M|re.I )).group(1) ". I am just starting off in python and webscraping..

Comment: group(0) returns the whole match, group(1) returns the capturing group which is in the parenthesis(.*) , re.M|re.I are the flags for multiline and ignoring case while searching. you can refer this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

Comment: Great !! Thats helpful .. and can you explain what you did with the subjects ?

Comment: It's just the HTML structure which defines the regular expression, you need to look a lot and find the perfect regular expression. I'm sure that there will be another better way to do all this. I haven't got enough time to reduce the length of the regex. That's it.

Comment: Yep ! I solved it .. I just added the condition "if (re.search(regname,string,re.M|re.I ))!=None: " for the whole scraping part.. Now it works fine. Although I am having a strange problem with my number loop. when I set the limits from 44 to 46 .. for some reason the code only loops till 45.. Any clues why that is ..?